# Re-export global variables with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm migrating JS scripts to ES6 modules. A common pattern of client-side code is to push tracking information to global arrays on the `window` object. One concrete example of that is [GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide?hl=en) `window.dataLayer` array.

I'd like to abstract these globals into ES6 modules, instead of instructing the linter to ignore them with `/* global dataLayer */`, as it makes the code easier to understand. My first try was to create shims like these:

```
export default window.dataLayer;
```

However, as explained [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) in the "Implementing Views" section, the above code is equivalent to:

```
const *default* = window.dataLayer; // *not* legal JavaScript
export { *default* as default };
```

As such, the `window.dataLayer` array within each module would be a copy of the original `window.dataLater` array: when GTM bootstraps, asynchronously, the events pushed from the modules won't be seen by it as only the local `*default*` would have those events.

What is the recommended way to deal with globals like these with ES6 modules, which does not involve heavy-weight solution like using a Proxy? It does feel bad having lots of globals around in a modular system.

Comment: Nothing in your example makes a copy of the array, so I'm not sure what you're really asking.

Comment: The sentence "*As such, the `window.dataLayer` array within each module would be a copy of the original `window.dataLater` array*" doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to what you describe in the question, the proper way to deal with this would be:

```
/* data-layer.js */
window.dataLayer = [];
export default window.dataLayer;
```

...and any modules that needed to push on to the "dataLayer" array, would just need something like:

```
import dataLayer from 'data-layer';

// ... some code I assume

dataLayer.push({
  'pageCategory': 'signup',
  'visitorType': 'high-value'
});
```

Because ES6 imports pass a read-only reference to the export, so it's not a copy of the array you are importing, it is the array created and exported in data-layer.js.

But the tricky part there then is then you'll have to modify the Google Tag Manager *container snippet* to not run as soon as it is loaded, but rather to only run after all the scripts that may modify `dataLayer` have run.

If you are loading the **GTM Container Snippet** as a module on it's own, you may want to import all the scripts that may modify the dataLater first (and make sure that part actually runs) before you invoke the snippet.

Something like:

```
/* gtm-container.js */
import 'this';
import 'that';
import otherThing from 'the-other-thing'; // lets assume it returns a promise
import dataLayer from 'data-layer'l

otherThing.then(value => {
   invokeSnippet()
})
.catch(err => {
   handleError(err);
});

function invokeSnippet() {
(function(w,d,s,i){dataLayer.push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX')
}
```

But, you know that's not really an explanation of how to do that, just an idea, I have no idea what different things may add to the dataLayer and because you are moving to an asynchronous module pattern, you are going to have to understand how running all these scripts asynchronously are going to change how you use the GTM system, which was *clearly* written to run synchronously using globals.

I wonder if Google will update these things with modern JavaScript soon, or if there is a more modular option available.

### I should mention in case you don't know:

Many (most) ES6/ES2015 features, **including modules**, are not available in browsers as of today (Jan 2016), so you'll need some sort of build or loader in place to make these things work in the browser (Like webpack, browserify, stealjs, jspm, or something with babel or tracuer or something)

http://stealjs.com/ is probably the easiest to get started with.